# Show background notification using conditions - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an App where the user will receive a notification if any other user likes his picture.

I'm able to handle in-App notification and apply my conditions without any problem.

Unfortunately, I am not able to handle the background Notification.

This is what I did so far:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (1 > 1) {
    print('send it');
    return true;
  } else {
    print('don\'t send it');
    return false;
  }
}
```

No matter what I do under _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler, notification will be shown anyways.

My handler is triggered and I can see the `print` in Console.

I believe there is another handle inside the FCM SDK that handles this notification, and the FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage is just an option.

Any thoughts? thank you!

Comment: could you show me the full dart file in which you put your `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler' method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to handle the background message is fine but there is more to know how the FCM really works.

First of all, Firebase Provide us two types of messaging

1. Notification Message

   FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-
   visible keys and an optional data payload of custom key-value pairs
2. Data Message

   The client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have
   only custom key-value pairs with no reserved key names

Now for your scenario, you should send your message from `Firebase` as `Data Message` then you have control of it, otherwise, if you send the `Notification Message` from `Firebase` the notification will show automatically.

Here are example sample snippets of two different types of `Firebase Message`

1. Notification Message:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Data Message

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, I recommend you take a look at the official documentation [About FCM message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: Hi Saiful! Thank you for your answer.
 
My notification is sent by a cloud function, and I was able to achieve my goal by removing the token of that specific device while logging out, from the application. 

So in this case, the user will only receive the notification if he is logged in.

Now, I'm trying to prevent the user to receive many notifications if the user "likes" his picture many times in a row.
Do you have any thoughts in regards to that?
Once again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: do you mean that if the user likes his won photo then you don't want to send the notification?

Comment: First of all I think my answer is potentially explains the scenario that your question requires. Could you please accept this as potential answer?

Comment: I have accepted your answer and I thank you for that. My second concern is how to prevent a notification to be sent repeatedly. let's say a user keeps liking / unlinking the same picture many times, this will trigger the notification repeatedly. 
so I am thinking of a way to prevent that.

Comment: You can count the event that the user clicked on the like and unlike button and after a certain number of events you can stop to triggering your notification.